# Changing Context root in Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using Spring version 4.3.0.On running my project my url falls as http://localhost:8082/myapp-1.0.0/#/  . But i want it to be http://localhost:8082/myapp/#/ . I have given server.contextPath = /myapp in my application.properties. what else i need to do to chnage the url?

Comment: try renaming the war file to `<build>
  <finalName>finalName</finalName>
 . . .
</build>` I think tomcat is taking the war file name instead of the context path

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Sumit sagar . Your prediction is also my guess. But I already gave like that.But it didn't work.

Comment: please refer to this url: `http://www.itgo.me/a/x8869372343142862926/spring-boot-not-able-to-override-context-path-from-application-yml`"When you deploy your application as a war file to an external servlet container Spring Boot's server isn't being used so configuring its context path has no effect. If you want to configure the context path you'll need to rename your war file or use one of the other mechanisms supported by Tomcat such as using a context.xml file in your war."

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-how-to-change-web-project-context-root/ This will do for you.